# Trying to prove the volume of a sphere by integration using trig functions

Tags: integration, trigonometry, solution-verification, spheres

[image]

$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$

$y = \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$

If we assume that $y$ is the radius of a circle, or "disc", inside the sphere, the area of it would be $\pi(\sqrt{r^2-x^2})^2=\pi(r^2-x^2)$

If we made this into a function and accumulated the area of each one these circles, or "discs", inside the sphere we would get the volume of the sphere.

$f(x)=\pi r^2-\pi x^2$

$2\int_0^r{f(x)}dx=\frac{4\pi r^3}{3}$

This works as predicted. However when I replaced $x$ and $y$, with $r\cdot cos(\theta)$ and $r\cdot sin(\theta)$ respectively (because $sin(\theta)=\frac{y}{r}$ and $cos(\theta)=\frac{x}{r}$), it didn't work.

The function $f$ became $f(\theta)=\pi r^2-\pi r^2cos^2(\theta)$

According to Symbolab or Photomath the prime function $F$ became $F(\theta)= r^2\pi \theta-\frac{\pi }{2}r^2\left(\theta+\frac{1}{2}\sin \left(2\theta\right)\right)$

Taking $F$ over the interval $[0^o, 180^o]$, or $[0^o, 90^o]$ then multiplying by $2$, gives completely unexpected results. Even when using radians to define the interval $[0, \pi]$.

Since radians are defined for the unit circle, which has a radius of $1$, and I'm trying to prove this for any sphere, I thought this might have been the issue. But even when using more general terms for the interval such as $[0, \pi r]$ still doesn't give the correct answer. Why?

Comment: Exactly what Andrei said in his answer and the integral is $ \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi}  (\pi r^2-\pi r^2 \cos^2\theta) \ r \sin\theta \ d\theta$

Comment: So $\pi r^2-\pi r^2cos^2\theta$ is being multiplied by $rsin\theta$?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you went from $f(x)$, by replacing $x$ with $r\cos\theta$, and, even though you did not write it, it seems that you replaced $dx$ with $d\theta$. Just by looking at the units, this seems wrong. One is units of length, the other has units of angle (dimensionless). You forgot the Jacobian transformation. For this case: $$\left|\frac{dx}{d\theta}\right|=r\sin\theta$$
So you need to replace $dx$ with $r\sin\theta d\theta$. Then, if you use radians for $\theta$ you will get the right answer.

Comment: I've been frequently trying to understand this, but It's just not clicking. Can you point me to the part of mathematics that deals with this type of problems? Maybe then I will better understand your answer.

Comment: I just don't see why the integral of $f(θ)=πr^2−πr^2cos^2(θ)$ over the specified interval doesn't return the proper result. I mean $f$ literally gives the area of a disc inside the sphere. So shouldn't the integral over the interval for all the discs inside the spheres give the volume for the sphere?

Comment: I understand the variables have switched, but if you look at $f$ as an independent function, in other words ignore the fact that it was derived from the previous function, shouldn't the disc logic still apply?

Comment: The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) article is a good start. What it means that when you change the variables, in this case from $x$ to $\theta$, your integration element $d\theta$ is not the same "length" as $dx$, so you need to weight it. In fact, in this case the weight changes with $\theta$

Comment: Just to illustrate my point, look at a simple 1D integral: $$\int_0^1 x^2 dx=\frac13$$
You can use $y=x^2$, but the original integral is not equal to $$\int_0^1 y dy$$